# How to access files in different directories in one Pycharm project without using absolute path?

Tags: pycharm

I have one Pycharm project that contains different directories as content roots (configured in 'project structure'). These folders are on different drives (D or E in the following example). The structure looks like below:

```
PycharmProject
--folderA (E:\folderA)
----A.py
----A.csv
--folderB (D:\Data\results\folderB)
----B.csv
```

With A.py, I can easily access A.csv using

```
with open('A.csv') as file:
```

My question is how do I read B.csv with A.py without using its absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os.path.split` function.

```py
dir_a, _ = os.path.split(__file__)
dir_parent, _ = os.path.split(dir_a)
dir_b = os.path.join(dir_parent, 'folderB')
```

Note: `__file__` refers to the file that the code is being placed in.

Comment: Thanks but this looks confusing to me. Also when I specify 'folderB' using your code, I have to use its absolute path, right? Is there a way to refer to B.csv using relative path?

Comment: The absolute path of the directory the source code is placed in will be stored in the `dir_a` variable. The second line shows how to retrieve the parent directory of another directory. You could insert another line saying `dir_parent, _ = os.path.split(dir_parent)` after the second line, in order to get up one more level, although that wouldn't be the optimal solution in that case.